# Is it correct to update Stack info without removing?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I have a Stack with a LinkedList.

I want to update a info of a element by id. (I'm using compareTo, doens't matter).

For example, my stack

Top-> john, mario, anna, michael

I want to update Anna's information (age, etc) in the Person object.

As I'm using a LinkedList, should I iterate the list and update the value?
Is it incorrect?
Because the concept is that a Stack can only access its top.

Should I pop in another stack and then back?
Should I iterate and update?

Thanks a lot.

My Stack:

```
public class LittleStack<E> {

    private SimplyLinkedList<E> elements; 

    public LittleStack() {
        elements= new SimplyLinkedList<>();
    }

    public boolean push(E obj) {
        elements.insertAtBegin(obj);
        return true;
    }

    public E pop() {
      return elements.removeFromBegin();
    }

    public E getTop() {
        return this.elements.getInicio().getObj();
    }
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you are exposing a stack then you can't iterate the list, you would have to pop and then push again.  As you are using a list to implement your stack, of course this can be done, but I would say if you have the need to iterate then perhaps a list is a better choice for your prohlem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that inside the class, it's possible. But in other class, only the top has access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem domain specifies stack(s) as the data structure, use a second stack.

In pseudo/code:

- create stack2
- pop elements off stack1 and push onto stack2
- repeat until you pop Anna
- modify Anna
- push Anna back to stack1
- pop elements from stack2 and push them on stack1
- repeat until stack2 is empty

Comment: It's really my idea. But the update operation is in the Stack class. I think I can do two ways. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's really my idea. But the update operation is in the Stack class. I think I can do two ways. Thanks a lot!